# Convolutional networks vs small signal features

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use convolutional network to extract some specific time series features. The signal contains some slowly changing component of high amplitude and small amplitude signal features (two magnitudes smaller) that I want my network to learn. In my case a sequence of [1,2,1] and [101,102,101] is the same feature class. However in case convolutional layer the second sequence would probably rather fit to some flat filter. (Or maybe my guess is wrong)

Are there any means to remove constant component, or slowly changing component from the signal, or should I just preprocess the data before I feed it in the network?

Answer (score 0):

Networks models the rate of change. The rate of change in both of them is the same, it will learn itself. Just feed it the data. If it is time series data, try LSTM + Conv layers.